# Jest configuration in Angular 13: transform not working

Tags: angular, jestjs, ts-jest, angular13

I'm encountering an issue with the Jest configuration in my Angular 13 project. The **`transform`** property doesn't seem to be working as expected, preventing Jest from transforming my TypeScript files during testing. Here are the details of my configuration:

Jest version: 28.x.x ts-jest version: 28.x.x Angular version: 13.x.x

In my **`jest.config.js`** file, I have the following configuration for the **`transform`** property:

```
transform: {
    '^.+\\.ts$': ['ts-jest', { tsconfig: 'tsconfig.spec.json' }],
}
```

However, when running Jest tests, I'm encountering the following error:

```
TypeError: configSet.processWithEsbuild is not a function
```

I've tried the following troubleshooting steps without success:

1. Updating Jest and ts-jest to their latest versions.
2. Clearing the Jest cache using **`jest --clearCache`**.
3. Verifying the compatibility between the versions of Jest and ts-jest.
4. Ensuring that my **`jest.config.js`** file is correctly configured with the necessary transform options.

I'm unsure what could be causing this issue. Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!